# IRLDocument Scanner Page Snap cameraview dismiss does not return to curent VC Swift XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am using IRLDocument Scanner in my app to scan documents. All works fine but after document is scanned and the scan VC is being dismiss (cameraview.dismiss) I go back 2 view controllers behind. Not sure if this is because of how the IRL Document Scanner is implemented or if I have something set to that particular VC that determines this return to it. If anyone encountered something similar please help. I have looked for segues and other things that could trigger this return but could not find any. What I am trying to do is to return to the VC that launch the scanner instead of going back to this particular VC. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dismiss function worked properly after using **present** instead of **show** when presenting the IRLScannerViewController an returned to the VC that has presented it:

```
let scanner = IRLScannerViewController.cameraView(withDefaultType: .normal, defaultDetectorType: .accuracy, with: self)
       scanner.detectionOverlayColor = UIColor.orange
       scanner.showControls = false
      // show(scanner, sender: self)

       self.present(scanner, animated:true, completion:nil)
```